# How to layout divs (thumbnails) from left to rigt with wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I would like to layout DIV tiles as in file managers. Without any reordering, strightly from left to right then from top to bottom. Automatically wrapping by the width of window.

[image]

How to do that? Any libraries appreciated.

Can Masonry do this? I don't need it to think where to fit next tile!

Comment: Are you using any HTML frameworks? How many images do you think you'd be using?

Comment: I am node.js + express. I will use hundreds of images, but they will for 2-5 in a row.

Comment: display or float will do that. where do you have a problem? any code of your attempt to show and share in order to be helped?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the width of the container, you get more/less columns.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [float](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) elements or [inline blocks](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp). For example use

```css
.variant1, .variant2 {
  clear:both;
  display: block;
}
.variant1>div, .variant2>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.variant1>div {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
.variant2>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="variant1">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
<div class="variant2">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Red elements are float, green elements are inline blocks.